# How do I calculate word spacing in a PDF document? For example:

Tags: pdf, spacing

For example:

```
20 0 0 48 20 500.0 Tm
[(H)6(ello)54(Wor)7(ld)] TJ
0 -1.1075 TD
```

There is no space (32) character in this array of text.
But somehow viewers understands that 54 is a space. But 6 and 7 is a char spacing (Kerning). Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the value is `54` and not `-54`?

Comment: Those 6 and 7 are not really "char spacing", but just *any* horizontal space. In this case they appear to be used as kerning, yes – but the `54` is not. By the way, are you sure of that value? These distances are expressed as 1000ths of an em (the current font size), and an actual space should be ~300 units.

Comment: Yes, i'm mistakably write 54, actually is -54:
[(H)6(ello)-54(Wor)7(ld)] TJ

Comment: The viewer does not understand that 54 is a space. It simply sees that there is a larger gap between 'o' and 'W' and inserts a space character in the copied text. This behavior depends on the viewer, some will insert the space character while others will not.

Answer (score 2):

The `TJ` operator is documentated in the PDF specification PDF 32000-1:2008 - Table 109 – Text-showing operators as follows:

> Show one or more text strings, allowing individual glyph positioning. Each element of array shall be either a string or a number. If the element is a string, this operator shall show the string. If it is a number, the operator shall adjust the text position by that amount; that is, it shall translate the text matrix, Tm. The number shall be expressed in thousandths of a unit of text space [...]. This amount shall be subtracted from the current horizontal or vertical coordinate, depending on the writing mode. In the default coordinate system, a positive adjustment has the effect of moving the next glyph painted either to the left or down by the given amount. [...]